# WSO2 API JWT roles missing

Tags: wso2, jwt, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

we are using WSO2 API Manager version 2.5 and Identity Server 5.6 where the IS is the key manager for the API Manager.

I enabled JWT in the IS config.
Added a custom claim dialect with userid and roles (as we do not need everything the local claim includes and it leads to errors in backend because the header is to big)

When I call an API the JWT is generated and passed on. However - the roles claim is not working in my custom dialect. 
When I use the local claim dialect for JWT the roles are included in the token.

My Config:

```
 <JWTConfiguration>
    <JWTHeader>X-JWT-Assertion</JWTHeader
    <JWTGeneratorImpl>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator</JWTGeneratorImpl>
    <ClaimsRetrieverImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever</ClaimsRetrieverImplClass>
    <ConsumerDialectURI>http://ourdomain.com/jwt</ConsumerDialectURI>
    <SignatureAlgorithm>SHA256withRSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
    <EnableJWTGeneration>true</EnableJWTGeneration>
</JWTConfiguration>
```

The http://ourdomain.com/jwt dialect looks like this:

```
http://ourdomain.com/jwt/uid
    Claim URI   http://ourdomain.com/jwt/uid
    Mapped Local Claim  http://wso2.org/claims/our/uid
http://ourdomain.com/jwt/fullname
    Claim URI   http://ourdomain.com/jwt/fullname
    Mapped Local Claim  http://wso2.org/claims/fullname
http://ourdomain.com/jwt/accountNr
    Claim URI   http://ourdomain.com/jwt/accountNr
    Mapped Local Claim  http://wso2.org/claims/accountNr
http://ourdomain.com/jwt/role
    Claim URI   http://ourdomain.com/jwt/role
    Mapped Local Claim  http://wso2.org/claims/role
```

This is the resulting JWT content:

```
{
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/version": "1.0.0",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/applicationid": "90",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/keytype": "SANDBOX",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/uid": "123",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/enduser": "mail.address@ourdomain.com@carbon.super",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/subscriber": "EXTERNAL/subscriber@ourdomain.com",
  "iss": "wso2.org/products/am",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/fullname": "Mail Address",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/applicationtier": "Unlimited",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/applicationname": "application",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/enduserTenantId": "-1234",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/tier": "Unlimited",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/usertype": "APPLICATION_USER",
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/accountNr": [
    "123451",
    "123452",
    "123453"
  ],
  "http://ourdomain.com/jwt/apicontext": "/heimdall/1.0.0",
  "exp": 1541605849
}
```

Any leads where I'm mistaken? Do I have to write a custom token generator?

Comment: Hello Mat, did you solve this issue?